# pyqt5 как происходит отображение следующего окна

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

запускаю главное окно , в нем есть меню выбора, выбрал что то , нажал на кнопку и надо чтобы в этом окне появилось следующее меню выбора например (полностью измененное), а потом только какой то функционал выполняется и отображается в этом же окне без каких либо признаков этого меню. Как происходит отображение ? это нужно удалить те кнопки когда запускается функционал, или создавать новое окно, а то закрывать? не понимаю вот этот механизм(извините за слабый вопрос, только знакомлюсь с pyqt, пока не нашел ответ в инете.

Comment: Опубликуйте пример, который у вас есть.

Comment: пример не в коде, а хочу понять механизм пока что. запустил программу, выводится окно с меню из выбора 5 например, после нажатия чтобы отобразилось новое чистое окно с другими действиями, вот как это происходит?

Comment: Давайте начнем по порядку, сделайте пример окна с меню выбора.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял тут нужен [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html)

Добавь туда несколько страниц и переключай наборы форм. Это как вкладки, только пользователь не может их переключать сам. Они переключаются програмно.

Например недавно делал окошко: на первой странице стэка выбор купить билет/ напечатать билет; вторая страница - введите номер билета; третья прогресс бар печати; четвертая форма оплаты; 5- подтверждение.

В зависимости от того что выбрал пользователь переходы по стеку 1-2-3-1 или 1-4-5-3-1. При переходе естествено надо сбрасывать и заполнять данные в формах.

Comment: это типа как вкладки, а тогда как происходит механизм изменения содержимого в одном и том же окне?

Comment: вы просто переключаете вкладку в зависимости от логики программы.